# EF Core 2.1 evaluates locally when Sum complex and Grouping

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I'm using EF Core 2.1 and query don't evaluates on SQL server side.

Model using in this query is:

```
public class V_TurnoverByDivision
{      
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public decimal LineAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PostingDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitCostLcy { get; set; }
    public string DivisionCode { get; set; }
    public string DivisionDescription { get; set; }
    public string TopDivisionCode { get; set; }
    public string TopDivisionDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal RUCAmount { get; set; }
}
```

**This LINQ statement is run completely in SQL Server:**

```
return query
  .GroupBy(g => new { g.DivisionCode, g.DivisionDescription, g.TopDivisionCode, g.TopDivisionDescription, g.PostingDate })
  .Select(s =>
                    new V_TurnoverByDivision
                    {
                        DivisionCode = s.Key.DivisionCode,
                        DivisionDescription = s.Key.DivisionDescription,
                        TopDivisionCode = s.Key.TopDivisionCode,
                        TopDivisionDescription = s.Key.TopDivisionDescription,
                        PostingDate = s.Key.PostingDate,
                        LineAmount = s.Sum(ss => ss.LineAmount),
                        RUCAmount = s.Sum(ss => ss.LineAmount - (ss.Quantity * ss.UnitCostLcy))
                    });
```

and generates the following SQL

```
SELECT
    [v].[BIInvCNLinesID]
   ,[v].[DivisionCode]
   ,[v].[DivisionDescription]
   ,[v].[LineAmount]
   ,[v].[PostingDate]
   ,[v].[Quantity]
   ,[v].[TopDivisionCode]
   ,[v].[TopDivisionDescription]
   ,[v].[UnitCostLcy]
FROM [V_TurnoverByDivision] AS [v]
WHERE [v].[PostingDate] >= @__firstDayOfcurrentMonth_0
ORDER BY [v].[DivisionCode], [v].[DivisionDescription], [v].[TopDivisionCode], [v].[TopDivisionDescription], [v].[PostingDate]
```

**This LINQ statement works but performs the GroupBy in memory**

and I get  warrnings in the Output windows

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'Sum()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

**BUT WHEN I use this query**

```
                  return query
                .GroupBy(g => new { g.DivisionCode, g.DivisionDescription, g.TopDivisionCode, g.TopDivisionDescription, g.PostingDate })
                .Select(s =>
                    new V_TurnoverByDivision
                    {
                        DivisionCode = s.Key.DivisionCode,
                        DivisionDescription = s.Key.DivisionDescription,
                        TopDivisionCode = s.Key.TopDivisionCode,
                        TopDivisionDescription = s.Key.TopDivisionDescription,
                        PostingDate = s.Key.PostingDate,
                        LineAmount = s.Sum(ss => ss.LineAmount)
                    });
            };
```

and SQL generates query that should be:

```
SELECT
    [v].[DivisionCode]
   ,[v].[DivisionDescription]
   ,[v].[TopDivisionCode]
   ,[v].[TopDivisionDescription]
   ,[v].[PostingDate]
   ,SUM([v].[LineAmount]) AS [LineAmount]
FROM [V_TurnoverByDivision] AS [v]
WHERE [v].[PostingDate] >= @__firstDayOfcurrentMonth_0
GROUP BY [v].[DivisionCode]
        ,[v].[DivisionDescription]
        ,[v].[TopDivisionCode]
        ,[v].[TopDivisionDescription]
        ,[v].[PostingDate]
```

How to solve problem with:

```
RUCAmount = s.Sum(ss => ss.LineAmount - (ss.Quantity * ss.UnitCostLcy))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is EF Core `GroupBy` translation limitation (probably will be resolved in some future version). In order to be translatable to SQL, the aggregate method expression should be simple property accessor.

That's why

```
s.Sum(ss => ss.LineAmount)
```

translates, but

```
s.Sum(ss => ss.LineAmount - (ss.Quantity * ss.UnitCostLcy))
```

doesn't.

Hence the solution is to pre-select the expression(s) needed for aggregates. One way to do that is to use the [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Queryable_GroupBy__3_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___2___) overload with element selector:

```
return query
   .GroupBy(e => new // Key
   { 
       e.DivisionCode,
       e.DivisionDescription,
       e.TopDivisionCode,
       e.TopDivisionDescription,
       e.PostingDate
   },
   e => new // Element
   {
       e.LineAmount,
       RUCAmount = e.LineAmount - (e.Quantity * e.UnitCostLcy) // <--
   })
  .Select(g => new V_TurnoverByDivision
  {
      DivisionCode = g.Key.DivisionCode,
      DivisionDescription = g.Key.DivisionDescription,
      TopDivisionCode = g.Key.TopDivisionCode,
      TopDivisionDescription = g.Key.TopDivisionDescription,
      PostingDate = g.Key.PostingDate,
      LineAmount = g.Sum(e => e.LineAmount),
      RUCAmount = g.Sum(e => e.RUCAmount) // <--
  });
```